# iterated function permutation with multiple inputs

Tags: functions, permutations

For any given function f that takes two inputs, x and y, and for any arbitrary amount of iterations, where both x and y could be any arbitrary real number would the ordering of possible y inputs be commutative?  For example can I prove

f(f(f(x, n<sub>0</sub>), n<sub>1</sub>), n<sub>2</sub>)

would always be equal to

f(f(f(x, n<sub>1</sub>), n<sub>2</sub>), n<sub>0</sub>)

for any arbitrary amount of n values and for any arbitrary ordering of those n values?

Comment: Here's a simple counterexample via Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x9ndorvotu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. For example, consider $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x+y}$. Then you can check that
$$
\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+3} = f(f(1,2),3) \neq f(f(1,3),2) = 2.
$$